# One form with multiple submit actions

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML with three links and a form, and three PHP scripts: send1.php, send2.php, send3.php.

```
            <a id=""  name="signup1" href="#signup" >1-Send form one</a>
            <a id=""  name="signup2" href="#signup" >2-Send form two</a>
            <a id=""  name="signup3" href="#signup" >3-Send form three</a>

            <div id="signup"> 
                <form action="send_form_x.php">                     
                    <input id="" name="" type="text">
                    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

First the user clicks on one of the three links to show and fill the form. When he clicks on "send" button, I want that the html form call the right action, according to the clicked link. If the user clicks on "2-Send form two", send2.php must be executed, If he clicks on "3-Send form three", then send3.php must be executed. 
I don't want to write a form for each link, how to achieve this please?

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to do this. Do you know JavaScript?

Comment: @Diodeus I'm new to javascript, how can I done this using pure JavaScript please?

Comment: JS can be disabled, I would use server-side myself. It's more effective. Build seperate functions.

Comment: It's a matter of personal taste, yet like I said, JS can be disabled by the user, rendering your method useless.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing what you're trying to do.

The easiest way would be to add another parameter to your form, and have the form submit to 1 php page which calls one of the other 3 pages depending on the value of that parameter.

You can either add some radio buttons to your form, or add a hidden input and change the value with javascript whenever the user clicks one of the 3 links.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could submit 3 times using AJAX ? Here is a simple tutorial using jQuery sending 1 form: http://vimeo.com/1392589.

Do it 3 times :

```
$("form").on("submit", function() {
  $.ajax(...) // do the ajax call 1
  $.ajax(...) // do the ajax call 2
  $.ajax(...) // do the ajax call 3
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript for checking which link was clicked

```
<a id=""  name="signup1" href="#signup" onclick="testFunction(signup1)>1-Send form one</a>
<a id=""  name="signup2" href="#signup" onclick="testFunction(signup2)>2-Send form two</a>
<a id=""  name="signup3" href="#signup" onclick="testFunction(signup3) >3-Send form three</a>
         <div id="signup"> 
            <form action="send_form_x.php">   
                <input id="clickedLink" type="hidden">
                <input id="" name="" type="text">
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div> 

//JavaScript            
function testFunction(signup){
document.getElementById("clickedLink").value = signup;
}
```